# PC Power supply for a PC/104. Current output

Tags: power-supply, current

I have to do some work on a PC/104 [CPU board](http://www.eurotech.com/en/products/embedded+boards/pc104+cpu+modules/cpu+pc104/isis+xl). Until now I have been powering this from a separate power module (acs-5151 at the same link) that took in 8-40V and gave +12, +5, and +3.3 out. Until now, I was able to power the CPU module with the 5V line but don't have access to that anymore. The CPU module is an 8W system and in the past we were able to see that it was only drawing about 0.5A. I tried using a small lab power supply but it didn't boot up the CPU (although some of the LEDs did light up). As this supply says it is only capable of 0.75A continuous I thought that perhaps this wasn't enough to boot the it up. Then I was thinking that I could use the 5V line from a normal PC power supply. When I check the supply though it says 5V /22A. A friend suggested that the CPU might only draw what it needs but wasn't sure. I'm afriad to try it as it's a very expensive piece of hardware and can't afford to damage it.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me whether a PC power supply will only give the current needed or if there a danger of it damaging the PC/104 module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only draw what it needs.  The .75A supply probably didn't work because the board will draw more at startup and the supply couldn't source it.

Comment: agreed, the 22A rating is the maximum current the power supply can source at 5V.

Comment: Ok guys, done it. It works :) Thanks very much for the reassurance.